# Mongoose populate not works correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a **Node.js/Express** app. I have 2 models with one-to-many relations (the system and its cameras). When I log the query result, there are no cameras but when I log the `system.cameras` it's OK and works fine. I want to send a response to the client with cameras but it's not working correctly. Here are the relations :

system.js model

```js
...
systemSchema.virtual("cameras", {
  ref: "Camera",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "systemId",
})
```

camera.js model

```js
...
cameraSchema.virtual("system", {
  ref: "System",
  localField: "systemId",
  foreignField: "_id",
})
```

SystemController.js

```js
const systems = await System.find({}).populate("cameras")
```

result:

```js
console.log(systems[0])         // show system without cameras
console.log(systems[0].cameras) // show cameras correctly
```

Comment: add log on systems[0] here!

Comment: `{_id: "63275c359b668be4c7aaad6d", name: "system 1"}` @Jackson

Comment: const systems = await System.find({}).populate("cameras").lean();
           
try it, what will be?

Comment: Thank you!! That works fine. If you want add it to answer. @Jackson